# Cannot find control with path when displaying dynamic FormControlNames - Angular Reactive Forms

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have built a [reactive form](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) where the form gets built dependant of the data.

[stackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g5rsaz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

In my example a user selects an option from a `<select>` this triggers a `(change)` method that gets more data which may add more fields to the form via `addControl`.

```
<div formArrayName="fields">
  <ng-container
    *ngFor="let item of fields; let i = index"
    formGroupName="linkTypeAttributeForm"
  >
    <!-- this could be anything -->
    <input [type]="item.dataType" [formControlName]="item.displayName" />
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Are there any better ways to have built this implementation to allow me to specify the `type` and add an unknown `formControlName`? Any help appreciated!

I'm getting an Error `Cannot find control with path: 'fields -> linkTypeAttributeForm ->` issue.

Anybody know how to solve this?

[stackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g5rsaz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to change:

```
formGroupName="linkTypeAttributeForm"
```

to

```
[formGroup]="linkTypeAttributeForm"
```

`formGroupName` would be used for a nested `FormGroup` that always has a fixed name, e.g.

```
const someForm = new FormGroup({
  someControl: new FormControl(),
  someNestedFormGroup: new FormGroup({
    someNestedControl: new FormControl()
  })
})
```

```
<form [formGroup]="someForm">
  <ng-container formGroupName="someNestedFormGroup">
    ...
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

Because your `linkTypeAttributeForm` isn't actually nested inside `linkTypeForm`, it's effectively it's own top-level form, so it needs to be bound to the template as with other top-level forms, e.g. via `[formGroup]`